# Can't use users : Unknown database 'users'

Tags: php, mysql

I know that this question has been asked probably a million times, but none of them have solved this problem. I am using PHP to connect to my localhost databse with the PHP script show below:

```
<?php


// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
$DB_NAME = 'users';
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = '********';
$DB_PASS = '********';
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// A QUICK QUERY ON A FAKE USER TABLE
$query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username`='$myusername' and `password`='$mypassword'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

// GOING THROUGH THE DATA
if($result->num_rows == 1) {
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
header("location:fail.php");    
}
// CLOSE CONNECTION
mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

This is able to connect to the database, but it is unable to find the database 'users'. You can see from the image listed below, that the database exists, but it can't find it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5uuL.png

Any help that will resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your user has permission to access to users DB?

Comment: mysql_* == deprecated.

Comment: [either use PDO or mysqli since mysql_* api is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Comment: IIRC session_register() also is goign to be deprecated soon, but can't confirm this claim now, altough the manual says it exists upt to v. 5.4 (well, this might be a yes). Use $_SESSION['var'] to create a session variable

Comment: I have edited my post with new code using mysqli, but im getting this error now: Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'users' in E:\Sites\checklogin.php on line 9
Connect failed: Unknown database 'users'

Comment: my impression is you dont have acces to users db or you are connecting to another db server, check your credentials

Comment: I'm confused: 'it can connect' but 'it cannot connect'

Comment: It can connect, but can't find the database. Emilio, it is localhost, and all of my credentials are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the OOP interface to `mysqli` with the procedural interface.

Try this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {           // Changed to OOP version
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
exit();
}
```

Comment: It was worth a shot, but it still won't find the database in mysql. It doesn't see it at all. http://i.imgur.com/bHj9XeA.png

Comment: If you guys want to see for yourself what happens, please go to www.whoerfastdl.com (My website) and login with the credentials username: john - password: 1234

Comment: I trawled through some results on a search for the error code. I found this link: [http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f3/unknown-database-cron-php-77061/](http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f3/unknown-database-cron-php-77061/). This guy inadvertently had two instances of MySql running, and his PHP script was connecting to the wrong one. There's a fair amount of detail about the process he went through to fix it.

Comment: OK, in at the movies right now, but i will look into it when I get home

Comment: Good work man. Worked like a charm! Thank you very much for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in your `phpmyadmin`

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON database TO username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

then try to run your php code.

Comment: I have access to the database, i made sure of this before posting here. The command has been run, however, i might need to re run with the password. Will try now!
EDIT: Adding IDENTIFIED BY didn't help

Comment: sometimes GRANT command changes works after flushing preveliges.

run this -- **FLUSH PRIVILEGES;**

Comment: Like i said above, it connects, but can't find my database on the localhost